# Generative Classification vs Discriminant Function Models

Tags: machine-learning, modeling

I am studying machine learning and have been pondering the following question: 
Is generative classification or the discriminant function model more accurate provided that the utility function is unknown and why?

Comment: This question belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow, which is for *programming questions.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).